# ubuntu 16.10amd64 - Surface pro 3, power cover keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, surface

There are a ton of questions about the Surface device and getting the type cover to work. My non-power cover works fine, except for the trackpad. I'm trying to use "dmesg" to add support for my power cover, but I am out of ideas.

This is the type cover I am trying to get ubuntu to recognize.

[https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-298465700-Surface-Power-Keyboard/dp/B00IZMKM94](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IZMKM94)

Has anyone else been able to get it to work?

Could someone point me to a tutorial that explains how I could get it to work? When I boot into windows the power cover works like normal.

Sorry for all the details, but did not want to look like I did not attempt research on my own first.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

--dmesg output:

```
[   11.174031] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=07c6
[   11.174034] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[   11.174036] usb 1-2.2: Product: Surface Dock GigE --**NOPE**
[   11.174037] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    9.339542] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.365060] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    9.387942] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0900
[    9.387945] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    9.387947] usb 2-2: Product: Surface Dock USB3Hub --**NOPE**
[    9.387948] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    9.391590] hub 2-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.391919] hub 2-2:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    9.504897] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    9.646306] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    9.655284] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0901
[    9.655287] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    9.655288] usb 1-2: Product: Surface Dock USB2Hub --**NOPE**
[    9.655289] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    9.656509] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.657693] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    9.769687] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    9.873074] usb 2-2.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    9.891106] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0307
[    9.891108] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    9.891110] usb 2-4: Product: USB3.0 Card Reader
[    9.891111] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    9.891112] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 201006010301
[    9.896033] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0902
[    9.896036] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    9.896037] usb 2-2.1: Product: Surface Dock USB3Hub --**NOPE**
[    9.896039] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
```

I've tried placing the following in 10-evdev.conf & 50-synaptics.conf and reboot. no dice :( I also tried going through each product id listed above, still nothing. The best I can tell is ubuntu does not detect it at all.

```
#Power Cover
Section "InputClass" 
Identifier "Surface Dock GigE"
MatchIsPointer "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "evdev"
Option "vendor" "045e"
Option "product" "07c6"
Option "IgnoreAbsoluteAxes" "True"
EndSection
```